# how to get a different amplitude of a recorded sound?

Tags: c++, qt, file, audio, amplitude

**1-Purpose**

My purpose is to display a different amplitude of a recorded sound when I playback this sound, for this reason I have  to get (when playback) the amplitude of a **recorded  sound file**.

**2-What I've done**

I've used  QT function QAudioInput  and QFile to record.

I' ve saved the as wav , raw  or pcm  sound.

**3-Questions?**

Is this possible to get amplitude  of recorded sound ? How can it be done?

Thanks,

Comment: "display a different amplitude of a recorded sound when I playback" - so, if the amplitude is like 20%, you want to display a different amplitude - say 90%, while it's playing...?  Trick them in to turning up their amplifier, so the next song blasts them?  More seriously, wav/raw/pcm store the data uncompressed - you can just iterate over the samples and take a maximum or average or whatever suits your needs.

Comment: @Tony thanks for reply , but how can I iterate over the samples?

Comment: if you're streaming direct to disk, you can read back from there using [read (note use of `gcount()`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) e.g.  `char buffer[8192]; if (std::ifstream f(filename) { size_t bytes = f.read(buffer, sizeof buffer); uint16_t* p = (uint16_t*)buffer;  ... }`.  See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaudioinput.html) for an example of choosing endianness, bit depth.  Alternatively, read into a buffer as illustrated in the top example [here](http://radekp.github.io/qtmoko/api/qaudioinput.html)